# How can this query be optimized?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I need to write this query in postgresql 9.3:

> 26. List the most popular movie in each country. The most popular movie/movies is the one that has got  the highest average rating
>       across all the users of that country. In case of a tie, return all
>       movies order  alphabetically. (2 columns)

Tables needed:

```
CREATE TABLE movie (
id integer,
name varchar(200),
year date
);

CREATE TABLE userProfile (
userid varchar(200),
gender char(1),
age integer,
country varchar(200),
registered date
);

CREATE TABLE ratings (
mid integer,
userid varchar(200),
rating integer
);

CREATE INDEX movie_id_idx ON movie (id);
CREATE INDEX userProfile_userid_idx ON userProfile (userid);
CREATE INDEX ratings_userid_idx ON ratings (userid);
CREATE INDEX ratings_mid_idx ON ratings (mid);
CREATE INDEX ratings_userid_mid_idx ON ratings (userid, mid);
```

Here is mine query:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tops AS SELECT country, name 
FROM ratings AS r INNER JOIN userProfile AS u
ON r.userid=u.userid 
INNER JOIN movie AS m ON m.id = r.mid LIMIT 0;

~10 min
CREATE TEMP TABLE avg_country AS
SELECT country, r.mid, AVG(rating) AS rate
FROM ratings AS r INNER JOIN userProfile AS u
ON r.userid=u.userid 
GROUP BY country, r.mid;

~8 min
DO $$
DECLARE arrow record;
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE movie_names AS SELECT id, name FROM movie;
FOR arrow IN SELECT DISTINCT country FROM userProfile ORDER BY country
LOOP
  CREATE TABLE movies AS SELECT mid FROM (SELECT MAX(rate) AS m_rate FROM avg_country
  WHERE country=arrow.country) AS max_val CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT mid FROM avg_country 
  WHERE country=arrow.country AND rate=max_val.m_rate) AS a;
  WITH names AS (DELETE FROM movie_names AS m 
  WHERE m.id IN (SELECT mid FROM movies) RETURNING name)
  INSERT INTO tops
  SELECT arrow.country, name FROM names ORDER BY name;
  DROP TABLE movies;
END LOOP;
DROP TABLE movie_names;
END$$;

SELECT * FROM tops;
DROP TABLE tops, avg_country;
```

Thanks a lot in advance)

Comment: First of all: do not create table inside a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to `kordirko`s answer, but with one fewer subquery:

```
select country, movie_name, avg_rating
from (select u.country, m.name as movie_name, avg(r.rating) as avg_rating
             rank() over (partition by u.country order by avg(r.rating) desc) as seqnum
      from userProfile u join
           ratings r
           on u.userid = r.userid join
           movie m
           on r.mid = m.id
      group by u.country, m.id -- `name` is not needed here because id is unique 
     ) uc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Alternatively, if you want to get the list on one row per country:

```
select country, string_agg(movie_name, '; ') as most_popular_movies
from (select u.country, m.name as movie_name, avg(r.rating) as avg_rating
             rank() over (partition by u.country order by avg(r.rating) desc) as seqnum
      from userProfile u join
           ratings r
           on u.userid = r.userid join
           movie m
           on r.mid = m.id
      group by u.country, m.id -- `name` is not needed here because id is unique 
     ) uc
where seqnum = 1
group by country;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about window functions. But name should be in 'group by' anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use a plain, old-fashioned SQL - it is old but gold.

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT *,
      dense_rank() over (partition by country order by avg_rating desc ) rank
  FROM (
      select u.country, m.name movie_name, avg( r.rating ) avg_rating
      from userProfile u
      join ratings r on u.userid = r.userid
      join movie m on r.mid = m.id
      group by u.country, m.name 
) xx )
SELECT country, movie_name
FROM q WHERE rank <= 1
```